# Creating angular app in preferred version

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm new to angular.

I'm creating an angular app using

```
ng new <app name>
```

but here I don't know how to **specify the angular version** and I don`t know how to **check the angular version** of the created app.

Can anyone help me in finding a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the angular version in your package.json file:

[image]

You can also change the version of all or of specific packages here, and then rerun `npm install` to install your specified version.

Comment: can you please tell me from which line above i can get the version exactly @Lukas Ansteeg

Comment: Angular is a collection of packages, and technically you could have different versions at the same time, although usually you will need them all to be the same version.

If you somehow have different version numbers, "@angular/core" would be the one to check.

Answer (score 0):

In package.json of your project you will find the current angular version you are using it in your project.

Also you can go through below link  for knowing much in details
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart